# More Fields: Input "Values (if applicable)" is disabled

Tags: customization

I have create a box and some fields in it. One of them is of type select. In the field `Values (if applicable)` I cannot change the content anymore. The field is disabled. I tried to delete all posts which where using this fields but still the field is disabled. Is the only way to completely delete the field and add a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this plugin since a day and I noticed too, seems it is a bug. All you have to do is to choose another meta type in the list, then select the previous type again. And the field is enabled !

Now, I try to understand, if it is possible, how to give a "label" for each value...